# OpenCV Crosscompile for ARM: highgui error (GTK2+)

Tags: opencv, arm, cross-compiling, gtk2, highgui

I'm have build the OpenCV library from source for Zynq (ARM). But, OpenCV was build on the same PC for x86 (PC) also. Firstly, I can execute every example on my PC without any issues. Secondly, I am able to crosscompile and execute every program on the arm target, except the ones including highgui libraries, where I receive the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvShowImage, file /home/hristov/workspace/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 534
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  /home/user/workspace/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:534: error: (-2) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function cvShowImage
```

Yes, I have gone through the forum for solutions for this issue but some answers were unclear and I would like some more detail into this. I have created the OpenCV build for ARM build WITH_GTK and GTK2. Also installed libgtk2.0-dev, pkg-config

However, From another topic on this forum, I learned that the problem lies in setting up the pkg-config: http://answers.opencv.org/question/57945/opencv-gui-with-gtk-2-solved/

Q) Based on the above solution, Do you set the path for PKG_CONFIG_PATH on your ARM platform (Zynq) or on the PC platform (Ubuntu PC)? Because, it is already set to the described path on the ARM platform whereas it is different on the PC Linux platform. More details of the current path is shown below:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH in PC(Ubuntu):
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig

PKG_CONFIG_PATH in ARM (Embedded platform):
/usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/share/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig
```

If the pkg-config must be changed on my PC, to the /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/pkgconfig/ location, I cannot find any pkg-config in that location. Should I create a new one, by copying the folder from my target?

Q) Also, Should the GTK libraries also be installed in the Target Embedded system (ARM)?

Hope someone can help me with this solution as I have rebuild the libraries umpteen times with many different solutions, but to no avail. Thanks!

Comment: nearly 6 years without any answer !!!